# How to draw horizontal lines across multiple Bootstrap columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap grid which contains of three columns in a row. Now I would like to draw a line across all columns under every row I write in the columns.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it displays Now:

[image: now]

I would like it to be displayed like this:

[image: wanted]

Comment: Why not use a table markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css code just in class col and row define border (top, right, bottom, left) and manage with colors and size.

Try this:

```
.col{
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}

.row {
 border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```